# Html page margin in IE 7 while printing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

How can i set the page margin in html when printing html?

I know @page works on IE 8, IE 9. but, it's not working on IE 7. So, i want to know how can i implement the same behavior on IE 7.

Comment: could you show us the CSS you have written?

Comment: Prehaps add some of your CSS code that you already have... that could have us abit.

Comment: do not have the CSS code on IE 7.

@page is working on IE8+, but is not supported on IE7

Answer (score 2):

As you have pointed out and as confirmed by this article http://blog.orite.com.au/web_development/2009-04-09/css-implementation-chart-ie6-ie7-ie8/, IE7 does not support @page directives.

If you absolutely need to control this in IE7, then an option that you could consider would be to set padding on your `body` element in your print stylesheet. You can of course do this in `cm` or `in` or any other size of your choosing. As you would set this in your print sheet the result would not impact normal page viewers. The disadvantage of this is that you cannot control the top and bottom margins of each page. If you are only after left and right margins however, this could be a feasible workaround for you.

And here is a quick CSS hack to target only IE6 and 7 that you could use to prevent this rule from infecting the printed page in all other browsers: http://briancray.com/posts/target-ie6-and-ie7-with-only-1-extra-character-in-your-css/.

Comment: Top and bottom page margin is what i need, there is no spacing on the top of second+ pages and bottom of pages. this is the issue, there are several lines just cannot be printed out between pages on many printers.

Comment: This cannot be done in IE7 as far as I know. Given the market share of IE7 however is roughly 4% (http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/12/ie_market_share.html) so you will at the very least have something that works for >90% of your users. If you need to make it work with IE7 then perhaps a PDF export would be more suitable.